# Multiple command line tool targets in a single project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to have multiple command line tool targets in a single project? 
I'm writing C++ with command line tool, and could build the first target but failed for the second one.

I'm using Xcode 4.1, Mac 10.7.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple targets and build each of them from xcode commandline tools. You can specify the target from command line tool like:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator6.0 -target "HelloWorld"
```

and you can repeat this for each target. I also came across to building workspaces direclty you can check that out too.

Apple's Document about it;

> If you have multiple projects in the this
>        directory you will need to use -project to indicate which project should be built.  By default,
>        xcodebuild builds the first target listed in the project, with the default build configuration. The
>        order of the targets is a property of the project and is the same for all users of the project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html